# delete row having foreign key in another tables

Tags: sql-server

I am using MS SQL server 2000 database. Lets say we have three tables A,B,C. The primary key of table A 
is referenced from table B and C.
So if i want to delete row from table A i need to delete corresponding row from table B and C if any exists.
But real issue occurs when primary key of table B or C is referenced from another  tables and if this hierarchy is much deeper.
Is there any script or way which can tell proper order of table order for row deletion?

Comment: you need to turn on cascade delte is such cases

Answer (score 0):

Do a search online for `ON CASCADE DELETE`, as mentioned by Rob Nawaz.

These keywords were introduced in SQL 2000, and will give the behaviour you're looking for. I do advise caution - it's very easy to accidentally delete a LOT of records including ones you might not have intended.

No problem to turn it on then off for a quick manual delete, but I wouldn't use it in a production system. Just suck it up and delete the related rows.